# How to disable Wifi Password Sharing

Tags: wifi

My MacBook connects automatically to the WiFi of the hotel I am in using a shared password from my iPhone (apparently and without any request) and so does my iPad.

I need to stop this behavior and use different passwords on each device as I am in a hotel room and only 1 device can use the same password. How do I prevent the MacBook from logging in without asking a password?

I already cancelled the network from the list of preferred, after turning off wifi on all devices, but as soon as I select the incriminated network it logs in automatically anyway..

Answer (score 2):

You may have enabled iCloud Keychain on your devices. If enabled, WiFi networks and the passwords associated with them are shared:

> **What information does iCloud Keychain store?**

> iCloud Keychain stores credit card numbers and expiration dates—without storing or autofilling the security code—and passwords and usernames, **Wi-Fi passwords**, Internet accounts, and more. Developers can also update their apps to use keychain, if the app is on a device that uses iOS 7.0.3 or later, or OS X Mavericks 10.9 and later. If you don't see items stored in iCloud Keychain, learn what to do.

<sub>From: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204085</sub>

Comment: iCloud Keychain is off on iPhone

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!: in the most stupid way of course.. although I had full range in the room I literally walked out the door in the alley and magically I have been able to log in!!!

Thanks everybody for trying and help